# How to incorporate minified js file to ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I have an situation with addon tinymce rich text editor here is the [link](https://www.tiny.cloud/get-tiny/self-hosted/)
When I downloaded, I have only tinymce.min.js file, and when I put ito my bundle which is working by the way, in debug it runs texteditor just fine, but in release mode, I dont have richtext editor.
My clue is that I added minified file into bundle config and I think that app skips those minified files?
I've tried to un-minify the file with [this tool](https://unminify.com/), but it isnt work neither.

my bundle looks like:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/manager/phasesettings/details").Include(
                 "~/Scripts/App/Manager/home.js",
                 "~/Scripts/tinymce/tinymce.min.js",
                 "~/Scripts/tinymce/init-tinymce.js"
                 ));
```

Comment: I've had issues in the past with CSS files that use @import - they didn't play nice with the bundling API.

Comment: what is the relevance of your answer in this matter?

Comment: If there is CSS in this package that uses an import statement, the bundling can literally choke.

Comment: no, it doesn use @import command

Comment: It looks like it may be a naming issue: https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/4932

Comment: I tried this solution but it doesnt help.